# Adding one period of lag to all elements within a python array

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to add one period of delay between array 'a' and array 'b'

What I want the result to look like:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What I am trying:

```
for i in range(5):
     b[i] = a[i-1]
     b.append(b)
```

But it is populating array 'b' with 5s throughout,

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: numpy.insert NaN value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264516/python-numpy-insert-nan-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really understanding the first sentence, but it looks you are after something like:

```
import math


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [math.nan] + a
print(a)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(b)
# [nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [None] + a
>>> b
[None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```